# Floating lookback put, MC vs analytic

Tags: option-pricing, monte-carlo, exotics

I am attempting to price a floating lookback put using the analytic formula. (eg. can be found in Shreve's vol II stochastic calculus section 7.4 or on Wikipedia) and wish to confirm the result by using an MC estimator with geometric Brownian motion paths. Unfortunately, I obtain different results (analytic : 0.1429 vs ~ 0.13 using MC simulation) which I don't expect.

My parameters are the following vol: 0.2, T (expiry): 1, r: 0.05, dt: 0.01, t: 0, spot: 1.

Please find below my code:

[image]

[image]

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Hi there and welcome. In order for us to help you, please provide a reproducible example. Also, please copy the code into the question body (instead of the screenshots), and please provide the 'main' as well, i.e. the input and output to your testing.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of details and bad formatting. I will follow the guidelines for my next post. I believe the comment by @AkhiCTropChaud below has guided me to a potential solution.

Comment: OK, good luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simulate the maximum using the brownian bridge as explained in the chapter 8 of this course https://www.lpsm.paris/documents/71/probnum_gilp_pf17_wCJtiAO.pdf

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look. Would you mind explaining why my approach does not work (i.e why there is a discrepancy between the analytic and mc price)?

Comment: Plot your result vs number of simulations - has it converged yet? Calculate standard errors too, is your answer within 1stderr?

Comment: basically you underestimate the max since you discretize, you can correct the bias by taking a finer discretization and/or by simulating the max between two instants with a Brownian bridge

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very useful!